# Agrupar resultados de 200 en 200 SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Estoy utilizando nodejs para consumir los servicios de una api, una de las restricciones es que debo consultar los registros de asistencia para 200 usuarios por vez (limitaciones de la api externa).
Cómo puedo agrupar los resultados de mi consulta de usuarios:

```
SELECT identifier FROM GeoVictoria.dbo.usuarios
```

En grupos de 200 resultados hasta cubrir el total.

Pueden haber 678 rows, necesito agrupar en `SQL Server` 
200
200
200
78

¿Cómo puedo hacer ésto?

Comment: limit no te sirve?

Comment: Agruparlo en qué sentido? qué solo muestre de a 200 resultados?

Comment: puedes agregar la estructura de la tabla, asi puedo sugerir un query mas apegado a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es fácil usando ROW_NUMBER() y división de enteros.

```
SELECT identifier,
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY identifier) -1) / 200 AS agrupador
FROM GeoVictoria.dbo.usuarios;
```

Se puede cambiar el `-1` por `+199` para inciar los grupos desde 1 en vez de 0.

Comment: Gracias, justo es lo que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar

`OFFSET` y `FETCH ROWS` para mostrar los datos, además de eso necesitas hacer uso del `ORDER BY` e indicar alguna columna para esta instrucción

```
SELECT identifier FROM GeoVictoria.dbo.usuarios
ORDER BY unaColumna
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH 200 ROWS ONLY;
```

Si podemos `OFFSET 0 ROWS` le pedimos que no se salte ningún registro, es decir que empiece desde el primero que encuentre

Answer (score 0):

Pues es mejor que crees un Stored Procedure y envies el parametro de pagina;

Agrego el querie para dicho SP, puedes dejar fijo el numero de registros, y solo
envias el parametro de la pagina.

```
declare @RegistrosPorPagina [int]=200
declare @NumeroPagina [int]=2

;WITH pg AS 
(
  SELECT usuarioId as registroId
  FROM Usuario
  ORDER BY UsuarioId
  OFFSET @RegistrosPorPagina * (@NumeroPagina - 1) ROWS
  FETCH NEXT @RegistrosPorPagina ROWS ONLY
)

SELECT UsuarioId,nombre,alias,telefono 
  FROM Usuario AS u
  INNER JOIN pg ON u.UsuarioId = pg.registroId
  ORDER BY Nombre
```